# How to configure older project in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I want to run my older project after installing a new OS.

I have cloned that project in htdocs, but it is showing a 404 error in the browser.

I have run these commands:

```
composer install
composer update --no-script
php artisan key: generate
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: What OS do you run? If macOS, get homebrew and install Valet.

Comment: i am using ms windows 10